# How could I delete a tag in TDengine database?

Tags: database, tdengine

I'm using TDengine database. I want to delete a tag. According the document, I can write a SQL like :

```
ALTER STABLE stb_name DROP TAG tag_name;
```

However, I got an error information:

```
DB error: invalid SQL: primary tag cannot be dropped
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the error message is very clear, the primary tag cannot be dropped. In TDengine, the first tag is the primary tag which cannot be deleted. you can delete any other tags except the first one.